# Exclude domain from DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) in Edge or Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, doh

I run a local BIND DNS server for my own development work. I like the idea of DoH in my browsers, but it is interfering with my use of BIND - instead of getting pages from my local development server, I get domain squatting pages.

Firefox has a mechanism for excluding specific domains from being queried over DoH which I think would solve this problem and allow my local BIND server to do its job, but I can't find a similar option in (the Chromium-based) Edge or in Chrome. Does anybody know of a way to set exclusions in these?